# How do I setup apache to have two domains pointing to the same web app

Tags: apache-2.2, domain

I have a web app running on http://domain.com and I just bought another domain http://domain2.com.  Both domains are pointing to the same DNS servers and they are both pointing to the same IP address.

What is the best way or how should I setup my Apache config to get http://domain2.com/blah
to point to http://domain.com ?

So that...

- http://domain.com/cool-page

would be the same thing as

- http://domain2.com/blah/cool-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) ! (Note that `mod_alias` has to be enabled)

```
<VirtualHost * >
    ServerName www.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost * >
    ServerName www.domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2
    Alias /blah /var/www/domain1
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -3):

Create two virtual host entries and point each virtual host's document root to the same path.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost * >
ServerName www.domain1.net
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost * >
ServerName www.domain2.net
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: but what about the sub-folder.  domain2.com/blah ?

Comment: not sure why I was down voted 3x when my answer (A) closely matches the accepted answer and (B) the original post was not very clear and my response gives the intended result as the accepted one.  In other words, the original post makes no mention of keeping some content separate.  So whom ever down voted this, please be careful in the future!